# Hadoop MapReduce global counter

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I need a global counter in my application. When all of the reduce tasks are finished, I must print the global counter.

I have found a solution in [Here](http://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/). However, I wonder whether I can use a global counter with Hadoop streaming or pipes as I write my application with C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stderr output of the stream process.

I found this Jira issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1328

It has few patches , I guess you can find in those about how to do the global counters.

Comment: I need a global counter. So, i don't know how to do with it.

Comment: How to retrieve the values of the counters in Hadoop Streaming using Python?